# Capture last inserted id with JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am learning web development and I have a question about how I can use a variable. As you can see in the code, I can take the last inserted id and I checked that it works using an 'echo'. Now I need to capture that variable with the js to insert it in an intermediate table and I don't know how to do it.

```
<?php
include_once('conexion.php');
include_once('validar.php');

class Proyecto{
    protected $idproyecto;
    protected $nombre;

    public function registrarProyecto(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO proyectos (nombre) VALUES (?)";
        $conexion = Conexion::conectar();
        $resultado=$conexion->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->bindParam(1, $this->nombre);
        $resultado->execute([$this->nombre]);
        $LAST_ID = $conexion->lastInsertId();
    }   
}
?>
```

I was recommended to use JQuery but I want to know more opinions.

Comment: You can use "return $LAST_ID;" at the end of that function then whenever you call that function you can use "$new_id = registrarProyecto();" and do whatever you'd like with the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via ajax, and can return `$LAST_ID` from there and can display in HTML using JavsScript.